# Random sum of random variables and independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, independence

Let $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of integrable i.i.d. random variables on a probability space $( \Omega, \mathcal{F}, P )$ and let $N : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_0$ be an integer-valued random variable (e.g. Poisson distributed) independent of $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$.
Consider
$$
S(\omega) = \sum_{i = 1}^{N(\omega)} X_i ( \omega), \quad \omega \in \Omega,
$$
which is a random variable since for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
\{ S\leq x \} =\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty} \left( \{ N=k \} \cap \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{k} X_{i} \leq x \right\} \right).
$$
Additionally, assume that $Y$ is also a random variable independent of $S$.

> Does one have, for instance, $$E \left[ Y + \sum_{i = 1}^{N} X_i \Bigm| N = 1 \right] P(N=1) = E \left[ Y + X_1 \right] P(N=1)$$

---

Since
\begin{align}
E \left[ Y + \sum_{i = 1}^{N} X_i \Bigm| N = 1 \right] P(N=1) &= E \left[ 1_{\{ N = 1 \}} \left( Y + \sum_{i = 1}^{N} X_i \right) \right] \\ &= E\left[1_{\{ N = 1 \}} (Y + X_1)\right],
\end{align}
the question is, are $1_{\{N = 1\}}$ and $Y + X_1$ independent, provided that $Y$ and $S$ are independent?

Comment: Can we assume also that $Y$ is independent of $N$?

Comment: @kimchilover unless there is a way without that assumption.

Comment: If $X_i$ are all zeros and $N$ and $Y$ are dependent, then $S\equiv 0$ and $Y$ are still independent. But the equality $E[Y\mid N=1]=E[Y]$ does not hold.